# Which is the best simulation program to simulate type-II superconductors?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity, simulations

I'm currently doing a research project and I want to do a simulation on type-II superconductors being suspended due to flux pinning and seeing how changing temperature and applied magnetic field can affect its dynamics. Which is the best simulation program to simulate this?

Thank you